# Calculating maximum string length for printing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, printing, fonts

I am trying to calculate the maximum length of a string to print.  I have done so by using mono-spaced fonts, but these take up so much horizontal room on a page.  I really need to print more characters per line without reducing the font sized to almost invisible levels, so I want to use a sans-serif font instead.  Here is my current printing function:

```
    public static void printPage(ref PrintPageEventArgs e, List<ReportLine> CompanyLetterhead, Queue<ReportLine> reportData)
    {
        int xPosition = e.MarginBounds.X;
        int yPosition = e.MarginBounds.Y;

        int maxCharacters = 0;

        foreach (ReportLine line in CompanyLetterhead)
        {
            maxCharacters = e.MarginBounds.Width / (int)line.selectedFont.Size;

            int position = 0;

            while (line.text.Length - position > maxCharacters)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(line.text.Substring(position, position + maxCharacters), line.selectedFont, Brushes.Black, xPosition, yPosition);
                yPosition += line.selectedFont.Height;
                position += maxCharacters;
            }
            if (line.text.Length - position > 0)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(line.text.Substring(position), line.selectedFont, Brushes.Black, xPosition, yPosition);
                yPosition += line.selectedFont.Height;
            }
        }

        while (reportData.Count > 0 && checkLine(yPosition, e.MarginBounds.Bottom, reportData.Peek().selectedFont.Height))
        {
            ReportLine currentLine = reportData.Peek();

            maxCharacters = e.MarginBounds.Width / (int)currentLine.selectedFont.Size;

            if (currentLine.text.Length > maxCharacters)
            {
                string[] words = currentLine.text.Split(new char[] { ' ' , '\t' });
                string printString = "";

                bool endsInSpace = true;

                foreach (string word in words)
                {
                    if (word.Length + printString.Length < maxCharacters)
                    {
                        if (printString.Length > 0)
                        {
                            printString += " ";
                        }
                        printString += word;
                    }
                    else if (printString.Length == 0)
                    {
                        printString += word.Substring(0, maxCharacters);
                        endsInSpace = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                e.Graphics.DrawString(printString, currentLine.selectedFont, Brushes.Black, xPosition, yPosition);
                yPosition += currentLine.selectedFont.Height;
                if (endsInSpace)
                {
                    currentLine.text = currentLine.text.Remove(0, printString.Length + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    currentLine.text = currentLine.text.Remove(0, printString.Length);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(currentLine.text, currentLine.selectedFont, Brushes.Black, xPosition, yPosition);
                yPosition += currentLine.selectedFont.Height;
                reportData.Dequeue();
            }
        }

        e.HasMorePages = reportData.Count > 0;
    }
```

This function uses ReportLine class objects, which are defined as follows:

```
public class ReportLine
{
    public string text;
    public Font selectedFont;

    public ReportLine()
    {
        text = "";
        selectedFont = null;
    }

    public ReportLine(string txt, Font font)
    {
        text = txt;
        selectedFont = font;
    }
}
```

Now how can I make this work with fonts that have different widths for different characters?  I know that there is a function called Graphics.MeasureString, but this will only tell me the total width of the string at the selected font, so this means that if it does run over the edge of the page, it will just tell me how far it will run over, not how many characters will be running over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for [Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurecharacterranges%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  You could determine the ranges to pass to the method by splitting the string into words.  That way you can tell how wide each word is, for wrapping however you like.